# Cant send message via Discord API

Tags: python, api, discord, token

I wrote this code in python to send a message = "message" to my own channel (with 3 members). It is supposed to complete it and print "200" as a success, it instead doesn't write "200", it writes "400" and doesn't send anything to the channel.

In this question I removed the channel and the token and wrote "ggbro" instead.

```py
import requests
payload = {
    "contant": 'message'
}
header = {
    "authorization": 'GGBRO'
}

r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/GGBRO/messages',data=payload, headers=header)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: You have `contant` but it's spelled `content`, is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

its **content** not **contant** (random davis told right)

```
import requests
ID = "channel id"
PAYLOAD = {
    "content": "successfully sent"
}
HEADER = {
    "authorization": "i dont want to leak myself"
}

response = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{ID}/messages",data=payload, headers=header)
print("Message sent" if response.status_code == 200 else "Message not sent")
```

btw selfbot is bannable, use alt or bot token